# String object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm getting following error:
[Error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpd6S.png)

Can someone please guide what needs to be done to fix the error?

The following code snippet has purpose to check whether a particular word is present in a string.

x= 'this string is supposed to contain windows'
np.where(x.str.contains('windows'),'Windows','Non Windows')

Comment: not sure what you did, but `x` is not a Series, ensure to use `str.contains` on the Series you're interested in

Comment: Please use backticks (```) to post code snippets properly, and avoid posting screenshots of code.

Comment: Are you using pandas somewhere? If not please remove the tag, else explain how this is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

x is a string, and so you are saying str.str. Im guessing you copied and paster from a tutorial, but your code should look like this:

```
x='this string is supposed to contain windows' 
np.where(x.contains('windows'),'Windows','Non Windows')
```

This should work.

Comment: You don't need numpy for that… `'Windows' if 'windows' in x else 'Non Windows'`, this is likely not what OP is looking for (or incorrectly tagged pandas)